# what dose make my page load twice?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I trying to show my data Table content on the page by the following code:

```
<%

            foreach (System.Data.DataRow DataRow in _DataTable.Rows)
            {%>
        <div class="resultContentHolder" dir="rtl">
            <ul class="imgHolder">
                <li class="imgHolder">
                    <img src="<%=DataRow["houseImage"] %>" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="<%=DataRow["houseImage"] %>" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="<%=DataRow["houseImage1"] %>" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="<%=DataRow["houseImage2"] %>" />
                </li>
                <li>
                   <img src="<%=DataRow["houseImage3"].ToString() %>" />
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="infoHolder">
                <div class="title">
                    <span class="visitors"><%=DataRow["Estate_visits"] %></span>
                    <span>تعداد بازدید :</span>
                </div>
                <div class="address">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="addressHolder"><%=string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} ,",DataRow["Estate_neighborhoodProperty"],DataRow["Estate_street1"],DataRow["Estate_street2"]) %></span>
                </div>
                <div class="facility">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <ul id="houseInfo">
                        <li><span class="propertyType"><%=DataRow["Estate_propertyType"]+" - " %></span></li>
                        <li><span class="propertyFloor"><%="طبقه "+DataRow["Estate_floor"]+" - " %></span></li>
                        <li><span><%=string.Format("{0} متری -",DataRow["Estate_buildingArea"] ) %></span></li>
                        <li><span><%=string.Format("{0} خوابه",DataRow["Estate_BedRoomCount"] ) %></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <p><%=DataRow["Facility_Description"] %></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <%}%>
```

when i click a search Button,redirect to searchPage and fill a data table from data base 
But after exeuting, page's page_load method called twice after executed code and render the page how can I solved this problems thanks.

Comment: please give your full controller code and views html

Comment: @Shariful_Islam it's too long code but when I commented this section my problem go was solved

Comment: @Shariful_Islam i'd edit my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you click the button it performs a Post Back request, which essentially pushes a POST request to the server to make it load again. You can solve this problem by implementing Asynchronous JavaScript.

In order to do this you can surround your code using an UpdatePanel which will indicate to perform asynchronous post back requests.

Comment: So why when I commented li's tag my problems solved?

Comment: Look at your code when the page loads and see whether there are any post back handlers hooked up to it.
I suggest you take a look at the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx)